# How to delete automatic divs with automatic buttons?

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, button

I'm creating a simple library app as an exercise and have run into a wall i cannot cross for the life of me. in my app after filling out a form, the info is storred in an array and the array is printed with a for loop on a .book div in the .books div with all the info you've put in and two buttons: Delete and Citation. I've attached data-numbers to all the .book divs and delete buttons to correspond to the same number but i have no idea how to get them to work.

Idealy i expect to delete the div with the tap of the delete button it is on. I've googled for hours to find the soliution, tried to think of one myself but couldn't hack it. I add my html css and js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Book Library</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <style>
        </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="headerTitle">
            The Library
        </div>
        <a id="addBook" class="addBook" href="" onclick="event.preventDefault(); openForm();">+ ADD BOOK</a>
        <button class="login">
            LOGIN
        </button>
    </header>
    <main>
        <form id="form" class="form" action="get" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); addInfo(); closeForm(); createCard();">
        
            <div class="inputTable">
                <div class="inputTitle">Information</div>


                <div class="title input">
                    <label for="title">Title:</label>
                    <input type="text"  name="title" id="title" >
                </div>
                <div class="author input">
                    <label for="author">Author:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="author" id="author" >
                </div>
                
                <div class="yearOfPublication input">
                    <label for="yearOfPublication">Year of Publication:</label>
                    <input type="number" name="yearOfPublication" id="yearOfPublication" >
                    
                </div>
                 
                <div class="edition input">
                    <label for="edition">Edition:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="edition" id="edition" >
                </div>
                
                <div class="publisher input">
                    <label for="publisher">Publisher:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="publisher" id="publisher" >
                </div>

                <div class="placeOfPublication input">
                    <label for="placeOfPublication">Place of Publication:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="placeOfPublication" id="placeOfPublication">
                </div>

                <button class="add" type="sumbit">Submit</button>
            </div>
            
        </form>
        <div id="books">
                <div class="book">
                    <div class="title">Game Of Thrones</div>
                    <div class="author">George R. R. Martin</div>
                    <div class="yearOfPublication">1996</div>
                    <div class="edition"></div>
                    <div class="publisher">Voyager Books</div>
                    <div class="placeOfPublication">Michingan, USA</div>
                    <div class="btns">
                        <button class="btn">Delete</button>
                        <button class="btn">Citation</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <nav></nav>
    <footer> Copyright @ Justas Lapiene 2022</footer>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    --headerFooter: rgb(120,57,55);
    --main: #FFE5B4;
    --nav: coral;
}
body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(9, 1fr);
}
header {
    background-color: var(--headerFooter);
    grid-column: 1 / 7 ;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.addBook:hover {
    color: rgb(151, 148, 148);
}
.headerTitle {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.login {
    margin-right: 20px;
    height: 45px;
    width: 110px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    background-color: var(--main);
}
.login:hover {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
.login:active {
    background-color: rgb(151, 148, 148);
}
footer {
    background-color: var(--headerFooter);
    grid-column: 1/7;
    grid-row: 9/10;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

main {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    grid-column: 1/7;
    grid-row: 2/9;
}
#books {
    background-color: var(--main);
    grid-column: 1/7;
    grid-row: 2/9;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 300px));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax( 250px, 300px));
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    gap: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.btns {
    display: flex;
    gap: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.btn {
    font-size: inherit;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1ps solid black;
}
.btn:hover {
    background-color: grey;
    scale: 1.1;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
#addBook {
    color: white;
    display: block;
}
#addBook:hover {
    color: lightgrey;
}
.book {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    height: 60%;
    box-sizing:content-box;
}

.form {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    height: 85%;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: var(--nav);
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 10px solid grey;
}
.inputTable {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: grid;
    padding: 40px;
    height: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 1fr);
    gap: 15px;
}
.input {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 15px;
}
input {
    height: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    border-radius:  5px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    border: none;
}
input:focus-visible {
    outline: 5px solid grey;
}
.inputTitle{
font-size: 2rem;
text-align: center;
}
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
.add {
    grid-row: 9/10;
    height: 2rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 10rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: none;
    background-color: var(--headerFooter);
    color: white;
}
.add:hover {
    background-color: rgb(175, 77, 74);
}
.add:active {
    background-color: rgb(223, 83, 78);
}
```

```
const form = document.getElementById('form')
const main = document.querySelector('main')
const books = document.querySelector('#books')

const inputTitle = document.getElementById('title')
const inputAuthor = document.getElementById('author')
const inputYearOfPub = document.getElementById('yearOfPublication')
const inputEdition = document.getElementById('edition')
const inputPublisher = document.getElementById('publisher')
const inputPlaceOfPub = document.getElementById('placeOfPublication')


function openForm() {
    form.style.display = "block";
    
}

let myLibrary = [];

function addBookToLibrary (n) {
    myLibrary.push(n)
}

function closeForm() {
    form.style.display = "none";
}

function createBook(inputTitle, inputAuthor, inputYearOfPub, inputEdition, inputPublisher, inputPlaceOfPub) {
    this.title = inputTitle
    this.author = inputAuthor
    this.yearOfPub = inputYearOfPub
    this.edition = inputEdition
    this.publisher = inputPublisher
    this.placeOfPub = inputPlaceOfPub
}



function addInfo () {
    
    const newBook = new createBook(inputTitle.value, inputAuthor.value, inputYearOfPub.value, inputEdition.value, inputPublisher.value, inputPlaceOfPub.value)

    addBookToLibrary(newBook)
    
    
}
    
function createCard() {

    while (books.firstChild) {
        books.removeChild(books.firstChild);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
    const book = document.createElement('div')
    book.setAttribute('class', 'book')
    book.setAttribute('data-number', `${[i]}`)
 
    const title = document.createElement('div')
    title.setAttribute('class','title')
    title.textContent = myLibrary[i].title

    const author = document.createElement('div')
    author.setAttribute('class','author')
    author.textContent = myLibrary[i].author

    const yearOfPub = document.createElement('div')
    yearOfPub.setAttribute('class','yearOfPublication')
    yearOfPub.textContent = myLibrary[i].yearOfPub

    const edition = document.createElement('div')
    edition.setAttribute('class','edition')
    title.textContent = myLibrary[i].title

    const publisher = document.createElement('div')
    publisher.setAttribute('class','publisher')
    edition.textContent = myLibrary[i].edition

    const placeOfPub = document.createElement('div')
    placeOfPub.setAttribute('class','placeOfPublication')
    placeOfPub.textContent = myLibrary[i].placeOfPub

    const btns = document.createElement('div')
    btns.setAttribute('class', 'btns')

    const deleteCardBtn = document.createElement('button')
    deleteCardBtn.textContent = 'Delete';
    deleteCardBtn.setAttribute('onclick', 'deleteCard();')
    deleteCardBtn.setAttribute('class', 'btn')
    deleteCardBtn.setAttribute('id', 'delete')
    deleteCardBtn.setAttribute('data-attribute', `${[i]}`)

    const citation = document.createElement('button')
    citation.textContent = 'Citation';
    citation.setAttribute('class', 'btn')
    // citation.setAttribute('data-number', `${[i]}`)

    btns.appendChild(deleteCardBtn)
    btns.appendChild(citation)

    book.appendChild(title)
    book.appendChild(author)
    book.appendChild(yearOfPub)
    book.appendChild(edition)
    book.appendChild(publisher)
    book.appendChild(placeOfPub)
    book.appendChild(btns)

    books.appendChild(book)
    
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the reference of that div to the delete card method, if you're tracking divs with the array Id assign that Id to the div you want to delete. On the method delete card you can catch the event source and his Id. Then use that Id to get the div and use remove to remove it. Don't forget to also remove it from the array

```
    const book = document.createElement('div')
    book.setAttribute('class', 'book')
    book.setAttribute('data-number', `${[i]}`)

    deleteCardBtn.setAttribute('onclick', 'deleteCard(`${[i]}`);')
    //0ther approach
   deleteCardBtn.setAttribute('onclick', 'deleteCard(event);') //and use the data 
   propertie

   deleteCard(event){
   console.log(event) //localice the data property
   id = event.target.data
   const toRemove = document.getElementById(id);
   toRemove.remove()
   }
```

*write without try maybe don't work